# How to select an input form that doesn't have a label with React testing library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, react-testing-library

On this example, I'm trying to select the second input, change the value to some text and then fire the enter event. My main issue here is selecting the input since it doesn't have a label nor id

```js
<ul>
  <form>
    <input value="" />
  </form>
  <form>
    <input value="" />
  </form>
</ul>
```

If anyone can help with I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Are you using React Testing Library? Can you post some sample test code you've tried so far?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the RTL. So, I've been able to fix this issue by first selecting the input like this `userEvent.type(screen.getAllByRole('textbox')[0], 'some random comment')` and then selecting the input again and firing the submit event `fireEvent.submit(screen.getAllByRole('textbox')[0])`

Please keep in mind that I'm not well versed into how to use the RTL, so I'm sure there might be a better way to achieve this.

Comment: From a user perspective, is there a reason you don't have some sort of label next to the input? Or a placeholder in the input?

Comment: I've added a possible answer for you using the `name` attribute.

Comment: @ReturnOfTheMac sorry, I should have added more context. The app is a todo list. The idea is that once I click on one of the todos, it displays a form that on submits it updates said todo. That's why I didn't add a name/label on any of the forms.

Comment: Gotcha. I'd recommend dynamically adding a `name` or `id` while adding the Todo. Then use getByRole or getByTestId. I've added an answer for the `name` approach as I think it's better than id.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest adding a `name` attribute to your input fields as it's something you want to do anyway, regardless of testing. This way the correct values are sent when submitting the form.

```
<ul>
  <form>
    <input value="" name="firstName" />
  </form>
  <form>
    <input value="" name="lastName" />
  </form>
</ul>
```

Test could be:

`getByRole('textbox', {name: /lastName/i})`

**Side note:** You have 2 form elements, if both inputs relate to the same form they should exist in the same form tag.

Answer (score -1):

```
    const inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    console.log(inputs); // inputs[1] is second input
```

Here is `inputs`

[image]